# java cannot load dll outside jre

Tags: java, windows, dll, jvm

Why it seems that is impossible to load a library (.dll) in Java, if it is not located in /jre/bin folder. It's crazy, but I have 2 dll's:

- **aa.dll**
- **bb.dll**, which depends on **aa.dll**

If I copy these dll's in C:\Tmp the following code it is not working.....
If copy these dll'd in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin, the same code it's working.

The code, very simple:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("C:\\Tmp\\ftd2xx.dll");
        System.out.println("ftd2xx.dll loaded");
        System.load("C:\\Tmp\\JD2XX.dll");
    }
}
```

The error (result):

```
ftd2xx.dll loaded
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jd2xx in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at jd2xx.JD2XX.<clinit>(JD2XX.java:729)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at Main_02.main(Main_02.java:7)
```

To be more confusing, one library I can load from c:\Tmp (**aa.dll**), the other one I cannot (**bb.dll**).
This last one requires to reside in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin.

If somebody has any useful idea, I will appreciate very much.

I tought the JVM does not want to load possible dangerous, or untrusted native code? And if it resides in the jre folder it consider the code is safe? But it is jus an ideea.

**Thank you.**

Comment: I'm not really convinced this is a java question per-se, but more a Microsoft / Windows / JVM question. I think you should at least mention the brand and version of JVM you are using. Adding tags.

Comment: You need to use `-Djava.library.path=....` to tell the JVM where to find the DLLs

Comment: I am using oracle official's Java 8, update 25 (latest, for now), 32 bits version, the dll's are also on 32 bits. Anyway, it is very odd that the same library is loading if I copy it in c:\Program Files\Java...jre\bin.

Comment: I know about -Djava.library.path=...., but why using it if I specify an absolute path? The ideea here is that I want to package this 2 DLL's in a jar.... And, for using them, I unpack them in a temporary folder (Usres/XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp and I want to load them. Because I want to give to the end user just a single jar, without installer, etc...

Comment: One more comment, because I think is important: I am doing these tests on a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 (I have installed it few hours ago), without any additional drivers, etc... Because this is the idea, I want to see If final users can use my jar.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm the same:
Windows 7(64bit);jre1.8.0_102(32bit);DLL's(32bit);
Exactly the same but in my case one dll(aa.dll) is dependent on another bb.dll (aa.dll->bb.dll)
aa.dll can be loaded from anywhere (a projects lib path for ex), but only and only if I copy bb.dll to jre1.8.0_102\bin directory; No chances to load otherwise. Tried various combinations to set -Djava.library.path=project_path\lib, to set system PATH=project_path\lib, copy both dll's to windows\system32 - nothing helps, the only chance is to have it on jre\bin path.

AN UPDATE:

And you have answered your question your self. It's a security:

Go to -> Java Control Panel -> Advanced -> Mixed code ..
Set "Disable verification.."

and aa.dll loads successfully. Both stored in project_path\lib